# Setting inter-dependant properties

Tags: vb.net, oop, properties

It seems to me that the answer to my question might be a remedial level one - I'm just starting out with OOP - but it is just not jumping out of the available literature.

I am wanting to build a VB class for the properties of steam (water too for saturated conditions).  For those less familiar with steam tables, there are several key properties of steam: pressure, temperature, enthalpy, entropy, specific volume, isobaric/choric heat capacities and quality (defines a special sub set of steam/water mix at saturated conditions).  Establishing any two of these properties completely defines the state of the fluid though each can be said to be properties in their own right.

The numerical method for determining any of these properties from any other two properties is well established so that mathematically v=f(T,p) and so on is easy enough to code (a complex sumation in its own right but easy)

What I'm struggling with is understanding just exactly what the correct approach to defining and setting the properties of an object in my steam class is.  Any two of the above values would be input and the rest calculated.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Example code doubly so.

Comment: Great question – I’ve done a minor edit: the technology – VB – belongs in the tags (and *not* in the title, it will be treated as redundant there by the Google search); furthermore, the name “vbasic” isn’t commonly used and thus confusing (actually I’m just *assuming* you mean VB, I’m not sure).

Comment: Yes I do mean VB.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have more than 1 option here.

One option would be to make a constructor with all the properties to be added as optional.  then your code can fill in which ever properties aren't supplied.

You could also make all the properties private and use specific methods to get or set the properties based on supplied parameters.

I'm sure there are more options and each will have their merits and draw backs.  This should give you a start though.

Comment: But how do you actually *compute* the missing values smartly? I see a combinatorial explosion here.

Comment: Something to be figured out since I made it plain that my suggestions were only a start.  One way would be to use textboxes and checkboxes to get the minimum amount of data before setting the properties in the object

Comment: Computing the other values isn't that hard. There are formula published by IAPWS that hankd

Answer (score 0):

I've done some more reading and pouring through example code and the following is the solution I'm developing (I'm pretty sure it is the second option recommended by tinstaafl):

Declare all of the steam "properties" (henceforth referred to as SteamProps not to be confused with the class properties) as private variables within the class.

Create ReadOnly Property procedures for each of the steam properties using Get to return the appropriate SteamProp value.

Use the "Sub New()" constructor to instantiate a new object.  Pass two or three parameters to the constructor.  I'm starting with pressure and temperature because it's the easiest.

```
Sub New(ByVal NewPressure As Double, ByVal NewTemperature As Double)
    'Subroutine for determining other SteamProps from pressure and temperature
End sub
```

Once I have this worked out, I will overload the constructor to allow passing of any two values to the appropriate SteamProps plus a string that identifies which ones:

```
Sub New(ByVal Var1, ByVal Var2 As Double, ByVal VarString as String)
'Evaluate VarString apply correct method for backcalculating P&T
'Subroutine for determining other SteamProps from pressure and temperature
End sub
```

String options will be "p,T" ; "p,h"; "T,s"; etc.  (p, T, v, h, u, s, Cp, Cv & w being standard variable names for the steam properties in question)

Objects of my Steam class will then be able to return all property values once constructed. The SteamProps can only be changed with the subroutines used by the constructor along with some additional subs for special types of plant operations (e.g. heat addition at constant pressure, isothermal expansion, etc.).  I won't bother with an abundance of these methods, because the greater advantage of having this class will be the ability to create two objects representing different points in the process and comparing their properties.

This is the first OOP I've done and I greatly appreciate any critique of this approach.